# JAVAFX: automatically enter specific cell in tableview, after button is clicked

Tags: javafx, tableview, edit, tablecell

After 5 days of searching, trying and reading everything I can find, I have to post my first stackoverflow question. Because I am really desperate now and have no one to ask.

I have a simple program: a table and few buttons. And my problem is I do not know, how to make the program automatically "jump" into editing a specific cell in a table after a button is clicked.

Does anybody have a clue, how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Presumably your 5 days of searching including looking at the Javadocs: calling [`TableView.edit(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#edit-int-javafx.scene.control.TableColumn-) should work. Can you show what you tried?

Comment: Hi, of course, this is not working, tried it already in the code, made few sample projects just for this damn "jump to cell" editing and this table.edit(row, TableColumn) does not do that "jump to cell"

Comment: AHA: made a progress: i have a table.refresh() before that table.edit() for refreshing the table. After commenting out that refresh, this table.edit() is working. So thank you for kicking me again to test it once again differently.

Comment: Yes, it was it, after removing table.refresh() - does not matter if it was before or after that table.edit() - it is working as it supposed to be working.